# Learning programming as a hobbyist... the merits of C vs C++

Tags: c++, python, c

I will admit that starting programming on your own as a newbie can seem a bit daunting. However after toying around very basically in both Python and currently C++ I'm wondering if C may be more suitable for a hobbyist. By hobbyist I mean someone who foresees no real future in actually programming for a living but rather sees it (at least currently) as an interesting exercise. So while I would like to be able to do things I'm don't really see myself y'know making a 3d game engine.

I know that I don't NEED to learn C to learn C++. But from what I've read a couple of people have said that C is easier to learn because it's a smaller language. It seems like it would be more suitable to me given that, and I know that C is certainly fine for anything I'd want to do with it, and thus not really need to learn or use it as a stepping stone for C++. From what I can see C would be a) Easier to program with, meaning easier to get in and make things and keep one interested. b) lower level means more flexibility, whereas Python would be hindered perhaps by it's high level nature. C) Still widely used (though perhaps not to the extent of C++)

A lot of people ask about learning C to get to C++ but I'm wondering more about C's own merits in and of them self. I wonder if what I'm thinking is true or if I've been filled with misconceptions. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I can't really see either C *or* C++ as suitable for a hobbyist.

Comment: @Ignacio explain, otherwise your comment won't be of any help.

Comment: For a hobbyist who doesn't foresee doing extremely high performance work, I would strongly advise staying far away from C/C++. Python is an *excellent* language choice for a casual programmer, and "serious" programming can be done in it.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at this wrong.  What's your goal?  If your goal is to "learn a language" then you are wasting your time.  That is like investing your time into learning to use photoshop with no ambition to ever create any neato graphics.

Instead of focusing on the tool, focus on what you want to do with it.  If I learn how to use a power saw it's probably because I want to build something out of wood, not because I think power saws are just really awesome.

Ask yourself; what do I want to build?  Once you answer that then you set forth finding out which tools would be most appropriate.

Comment: +1. Power saws are really awesome, though. 8v)

Comment: @Fred Larson:  True... perhaps I should have used a less awesome example...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I would suppose that my most "intensive" goals are to write small programs (which would probably be in the realm of 2d image graphics) and 2d/2.5d games, in the realm of adventure games or sprite based rpgs etc (both of which can probly be done in python). I know it's not like I'm going to pull any of that out in the next 6-12 months but am more so looking at ways of keeping any unnecessary complexity out for the time being while still learning a low level language that is more broadly used. I look at it as knowing what's going on INSIDE the powersaw ;)

Comment: @paulb: You can certainly do that with C# XNA, python, whatever, without learning C or C++, which will be more difficult.  I would also recommend RPG Maker.  It is a "toy" 2d game engine, but it exposes a scriptable API in Ruby.  There are multiple user forums which have a ton of tutorials, info, and support (I am a moderator on two of them, old hobby) and getting started is really easy.  They have a free one month demo, the whole thing costs something like $60.

Comment: I suppose I come at it from the wanting to know what's going on behind the scenes so I'm not just scripting APIs. But I suppose you're saying do everything in Python if you're still interested after you've done all of that in python then come back and look into a lower level programming language. But I mean could you code something like Gimp in python and still have it run on modern computers without much issue? I suppose it's not knowing just how far Python can be pushed before it becomes too much of a burden on a PC. Make games like the year 2001 and back and I should be fine? ;) haha

Comment: @paulb: Ummm... no :).  If you're talking about performance intensive backend stuff (like GIMP or a 2D game *engine*) then you have just crossed the line into non-trivial programming land.  Of course you *can* program something like GIMP in python, but you're not going to write teh image processing bits directly in python.  You will end up using an API at some level.  If you want to do this from the ground up then a lower level language would be better suited.

Comment: Yes, I was meaning wanting to perhaps be able to do a 2d/2.5d engine. Though I find it surprising that python would be bad for doing even that since it doesn't seem that intensive for current computers. Yes I know that at some level people stop creating from scratch and use APIs but I would like to know the goings on behind the hood at least a little bit for my own pleasure. I suppose I will try C if it is to be in fact "easier to learn", though probably difficult to master :) Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not that you can't do it in python; you certainly can, and it would be a good exercise.  However, any "serious" game engine, even 2D, is going to be performance intensive and, as a result, python may not be the best choice.  You can certainly write an API in python and perform the low level stuff (mostly image processing) in C.  Go ahead and do it in python first.  If there are bits that end up being slow and that you just can't get fast in python then optimize at that point.  Image processing in a language like C is fast mainly because you have access to raw memory.

Comment: Thanks Ed and everyone else for their advice and patience. I've found a very good book (so far) on C, Programming in C by Stephen Kochan. It's straight forward, to the point and well written with many exercises and quizzes. I think I'll try and motor through this and see what I can get out of it. If it doesn't work out then I'll go back to playing with Python :)

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Learning C is definitely not a prerequisite to learning C++, but as you mentioned it is easier to learn as it is a smaller language. You can read [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) in an afternoon and know everything there is to know about the C language (although there's obviously plenty more to learn about "programming", design patterns, algorithms etc). There are very few people on this earth who know everything there is to know about C++.

Unless you're doing microcontroller (arduino, AVR, etc) or firmware development Python's high-level-ness won't be an issue at all.

Overall, for a hobbyist, I would suggest learning Python. If you really want to go lower level, I would suggest C.

Comment: It is possible to use Python for some microcontroller work. Firmware is still a bit off though.

Comment: Possible, but not practical in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: everything there is to know about C in an afternoon? what have you been smoking? :D I've been using C for **years** professionally and still learn new stuff from time to time.